# Euler's formula with base 10?

Tags: complex-analysis

Does Euler's formula ($e^{ix} = \cos x + i \sin x$) work in base $10$? If it does, how could I express it?

Comment: One may always write $$10^{ix}=e^{ix\ln(10)}=\cos[ix\ln(10)]+i\sin[ix\ln(10)].$$

Comment: @mdewey What ??

Comment: If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try converting the formula to base $10$.

Let $\log$ be the natural (i.e., base $e$) logarithm. Then $10 = e^{\log10}$, so:

$$
10^{ix} = e^{ix\log10}=\cos(x\log10) + i\sin(x\log10)
$$

Answer (score 1):

The formula does not hold, you can write:

$$10^{ix}=(e^{\log 10})^{ix} =(e^{ix})^{\log 10} = (\cos x + i \sin x)^{\log 10}$$